# Switching Android notification from FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT to cancelable

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have an ongoing task and after it finishes, I want the notification to become cancelable.

For that, I create a new notification with notification.flags as zero, but the notification keeps being **un**-cancelable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, `FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE` prevented the notification from turning into cancelable, even after reseting the flags.

After removing `FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE` and using only `0` or `FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT`, the notification could be made **cancelable** or **un-cancelable** - respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look here : [Android update notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating)

In short what you will do is this:

- Create your notification first time and assign a notification ID to it.
- Once your service is done executing create a new cancelable notification with the same id
- fire that notification, it should make the previous notification cancelable .