# How to cancel Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE

Tags: android

Let's suppose you wish to show a Notification with the foreground service flag, and use `nm` to display it:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(...);
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE
nm.notify(SOME_ID, notification);
```

The notification will appear. However, removing it is difficult, because this doesn't appear to do anything:

```
nm.cancel(SOME_ID);
```

how to cancel this Notification? stopForeground is not a solution because i amnot in the service.

Comment: That's odd. I would expect `cancel()` to work here. Do you happen to have a sample app that demonstrates the problem? BTW, it looks like this has been a problem for a bit at least: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24581

Comment: is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

> is there any solution?

If [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24581) is to be believed, then no, other than having a service call `stopForeground()`. You can send a command to your service via `startService()` so it can call `stopForeground()`. Or, you can create a tiny dedicated `Service` that simply calls `stopForeground()` and `stopSelf()` from `onStartCommand()`, just for getting rid of this notification.

Answer (score 0):

The solution its After removing FLAG_FOREGROUND_SERVICE and using only 0 or FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT, the notification could be made cancelable or un-cancelable - respectively. 
Works for me, the answer i found this was helpfull
[Switching Android notification from FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT to cancelable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924240/switching-android-notification-from-flag-ongoing-event-to-cancelable/14933931#14933931)